# Compactness implies that every net has a converging subnet - why that definition of subnet?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, nets

The definition of subnet is more convoluted than expected. The idea seems to be that the definition is such that the equivalence **compactness $\Leftrightarrow$ every net has a convergent subnet** holds.

In [here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/13.pdf) Henno Brandsma states that for the equivalence to hold we cannot define a subnet of a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ to be a net $(x_i)_{i\in J}$ where $J$ is cofinal in $I$. Let $(P)$ be the property that every net admits a convergent subnet in the (non-standard) sense above.

Onwards let subnet have its classical definition. Clearly in any topological space $(P)$ implies that every net has a converging subnet. So the comment implies that there are spaces that are compact but still not satisfy $(P)$.

> What would one such space look like?

Comment: [Which](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12042+subnet) classical definition of subnet?

Comment: Take any compact but not sequentially compact space (e.g. $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}$), and in that a sequence without convergent subsequence.

Comment: Say the definition in the link in my question. Anyway I guess you suggestion works. I'd still be interested in more examples though, say one that is sequentially compact.

Comment: I suspect that in a sequentially compact space, every net has a convergent non-standard-subnet. But I haven't thought much about it, maybe my suspicion is wrong. Again not sequentially compact, another example is [$\beta \omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110537). (These examples make use of the fact that a non-standard-subnet of a sequence is a subsequence.)

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046996/subnet-vs-cofinal-subnet) is an example that's not a sequence.

Comment: I agree that the term 'subnet' is not too lucky.. We could call it 'overnet' or something more descriptive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X = \{0,1\}^I$ in the product topology, where $I = 2^{\mathbb{N}}$ (or any other index set of size $\mathbb{c}$) is an example of a compact Hausdorff space, which has a sequence (i.e. a net with index set $\mathbb{N}$ in the usual order) $(x_n)$ without a convergent subsequence (I showed that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1558796/4280)). [$\beta \omega$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110537/4280) is also a classical example , but takes a bit more theory to define, also using sequences. Note that a subsequence is just the subnet determined by a cofinal subset of $\mathbb{N}$. So such an $(x_n)$ is a net witnesssing that $X$ does not obey $(P)$. It's because of the insufficiency of subsequences of sequences (and taking larger index sets and larger products we can also, I think, find examples for some uncountable index sets and their cofinal subsets, or use [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2047036/4280) etc.) that the more complex definition of subnet as used in Kelly and Engelking etc., came to be defined and studied.